# How to to put the value of a key in an object in an array based on the order of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of values, which match the object keys in the object. The array of values has the order of which the key's values should be in based on the keys (which again, match the array's values). I need to order the values of the keys based of the order of the blocks in the array.

Here is the Object:

```
var Payload = { 
BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141: {questions0: "QID4", questions1: "QID17"},
BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV: {questions0: "QID39", questions1: "QID38"},
BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz: {questions0: "QID9", questions1: "QID7", questions2: "QID12", questions3: "QID11"},
BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5: {questions0: "QID14"},
BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp: {questions0: "QID30", questions1: "QID31"},
BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1: {questions0: "QID5", questions1: "QID18"},
BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV: {questions0: "QID13"},
BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf: {questions0: "QID44"},
BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B: {questions0: "QID36"},
BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz: {questions0: "QID27", questions1: "QID24"},
BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx: {questions0: "QID45"},
BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr: {questions0: "QID29", questions1: "QID32"},
BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt: {questions0: "QID43", questions1: "QID42", questions2: "QID41", questions3: "QID40", questions4: "QID34"},
BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP: {questions0: "QID16", questions1: "QID15"},
BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9: {questions0: "QID46"},
BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr: {questions0: "QID33"}
}
```

Here is the Array:

```
 var Array =  ["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf", "BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt", "BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B",
"BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141", "BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR", "BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx",
"BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9", "BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV", "BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1",
"BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz", "BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz", "BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr", 
"BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp", "BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV", "BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP", 
"BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr", "BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"]
```

Notice that the array values match the object keys. The objects values should be in the same order of the arrays values so that they values are in the correct order.

I have tried the following, but I just end of with an array of the blocks again.

```
var ArrayOfQuestionOrder = []
for( i=0;i<Array.length;i++){

    if(Payload.hasOwnProperty(Array[i])){
        var objectKeys = Object.keys(Payload)
        var index = objectKeys.indexOf(Array[i])
        var OrderOfKeys = Object.keys(Payload)[index]
        ArrayOfQuestionOrder.push(OrderOfKeys);

    }

}console.log(ArrayOfQuestionOrder)
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Note that the code posted is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: I edited my response, sorry for the lack of clarity. Any ideas to get me started?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put the value of a key in an object in an array based on the order of another array with plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902619/how-to-put-the-value-of-a-key-in-an-object-in-an-array-based-on-the-order-of-ano)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the question values of `Payload` object put into a new array in the order mentioned in `Array`. In your code, you are pushing the keys to your `ArrayOfQuestionOrder` instead of values. You can simply achieve this by looping through the blocks `Array` and return the value of each key in `Payload` object using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array = ["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf", "BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt", "BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B",
  "BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141", "BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR", "BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx",
  "BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9", "BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV", "BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1",
  "BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz", "BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz", "BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr",
  "BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp", "BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV", "BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP",
  "BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr", "BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"
]

let Payload = { 
 BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141: {questions0: "QID4", questions1: "QID17"},
 BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV: {questions0: "QID39", questions1: "QID38"},
 BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz: {questions0: "QID9", questions1: "QID7", questions2: "QID12", questions3: "QID11"},
 BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5: {questions0: "QID14"},
 BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp: {questions0: "QID30", questions1: "QID31"},
 BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1: {questions0: "QID5", questions1: "QID18"},
 BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV: {questions0: "QID13"},
 BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf: {questions0: "QID44"},
 BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B: {questions0: "QID36"},
 BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz: {questions0: "QID27", questions1: "QID24"},
 BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx: {questions0: "QID45"},
 BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr: {questions0: "QID29", questions1: "QID32"},
 BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt: {questions0: "QID43", questions1: "QID42", questions2: "QID41", questions3: "QID40", questions4: "QID34"},
 BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP: {questions0: "QID16", questions1: "QID15"},
 BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9: {questions0: "QID46"},
 BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr: {questions0: "QID33"}
}

let newArray = array.map(key => Payload[key]);
console.log(newArray);
```