# how to put the value of a key in an object in an array based on the order of another array with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of values, which match the object keys in the object. The array of values has the order of which the key's values should be in based on the keys (which again, match the array's values). I need to order the values of the keys based of the order of the blocks in the array.

Here is the Object:

```
var Payload = { 
BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141: {questions0: "QID4", questions1: "QID17"},
BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV: {questions0: "QID39", questions1: "QID38"},
BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz: {questions0: "QID9", questions1: "QID7", questions2: "QID12", questions3: "QID11"},
BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5: {questions0: "QID14"},
BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp: {questions0: "QID30", questions1: "QID31"},
BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1: {questions0: "QID5", questions1: "QID18"},
BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV: {questions0: "QID13"},
BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf: {questions0: "QID44"},
BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B: {questions0: "QID36"},
BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz: {questions0: "QID27", questions1: "QID24"},
BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx: {questions0: "QID45"},
BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr: {questions0: "QID29", questions1: "QID32"},
BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt: {questions0: "QID43", questions1: "QID42", questions2: "QID41", questions3: "QID40", questions4: "QID34"},
BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP: {questions0: "QID16", questions1: "QID15"},
BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9: {questions0: "QID46"},
BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr: {questions0: "QID33"}
}
```

Here is the Array:

```
 var Array =  ["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf", "BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt", "BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B",
"BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141", "BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR", "BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx",
"BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9", "BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV", "BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1",
"BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz", "BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz", "BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr", 
"BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp", "BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV", "BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP", 
"BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr", "BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"]
```

Notice that the array values match the object keys. The objects values should be in the same order of the arrays values so that they values are in the correct order.

I have tried the following, but I just end of with an array of the blocks again.

```
var ArrayOfQuestionOrder = []
for( i=0;i<Array.length;i++){

    if(Payload.hasOwnProperty(Array[i])){
        var objectKeys = Object.keys(Payload)
        var index = objectKeys.indexOf(Array[i])
        var OrderOfKeys = Object.keys(Payload)[index]
        ArrayOfQuestionOrder.push(OrderOfKeys);

    }

}console.log(ArrayOfQuestionOrder)
```

The expected output would be

```
["QID44","QID43","QID42",...]
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output? Is it something like `[['QID44'], ['QID43', 'QID42', 'QID41', ...`?

Comment: Thanks, just added the expected output.

Comment: That's not in the same order as the keys in your `var Array` though - eg the first array item `BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf` has `{questions0: "QID44"}`, so might you want the output to start with `QID44`? (like what I posted in the first comment, except a plain array of strings, rather than an array of arrays?)

Comment: Thanks, fixed that too. Yes you are right, a plain array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` the `keyArr` to the `Object.values` of the associated object in `payload`, then flatten the array:

```js
var Payload={BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141:{questions0:"QID4",questions1:"QID17"},BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV:{questions0:"QID39",questions1:"QID38"},BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz:{questions0:"QID9",questions1:"QID7",questions2:"QID12",questions3:"QID11"},BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5:{questions0:"QID14"},BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp:{questions0:"QID30",questions1:"QID31"},BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1:{questions0:"QID5",questions1:"QID18"},BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV:{questions0:"QID13"},BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf:{questions0:"QID44"},BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B:{questions0:"QID36"},BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz:{questions0:"QID27",questions1:"QID24"},BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx:{questions0:"QID45"},BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr:{questions0:"QID29",questions1:"QID32"},BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt:{questions0:"QID43",questions1:"QID42",questions2:"QID41",questions3:"QID40",questions4:"QID34"},BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP:{questions0:"QID16",questions1:"QID15"},BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9:{questions0:"QID46"},BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr:{questions0:"QID33"}};
var keyArr=["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf","BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt","BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B","BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141","BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR","BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx","BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9","BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV","BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1","BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz","BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz","BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr","BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp","BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV","BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP","BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr","BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"]

const output = keyArr
  .map(key => Object.values(Payload[key] || {}))
  .flat();
console.log(output);
```

Another approach without the new method `flat` would be to `reduce` into the output array instead:

```js
var Payload={BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141:{questions0:"QID4",questions1:"QID17"},BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV:{questions0:"QID39",questions1:"QID38"},BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz:{questions0:"QID9",questions1:"QID7",questions2:"QID12",questions3:"QID11"},BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5:{questions0:"QID14"},BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp:{questions0:"QID30",questions1:"QID31"},BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1:{questions0:"QID5",questions1:"QID18"},BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV:{questions0:"QID13"},BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf:{questions0:"QID44"},BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B:{questions0:"QID36"},BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz:{questions0:"QID27",questions1:"QID24"},BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx:{questions0:"QID45"},BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr:{questions0:"QID29",questions1:"QID32"},BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt:{questions0:"QID43",questions1:"QID42",questions2:"QID41",questions3:"QID40",questions4:"QID34"},BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP:{questions0:"QID16",questions1:"QID15"},BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9:{questions0:"QID46"},BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr:{questions0:"QID33"}};
var keyArr=["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf","BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt","BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B","BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141","BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR","BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx","BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9","BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV","BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1","BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz","BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz","BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr","BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp","BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV","BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP","BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr","BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"]

const output = keyArr.reduce((a, key) => {
  if (Payload[key]) {
    a.push(...Object.values(Payload[key]));
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Or, if you're running an ancient browser that doesn't support ES2015, you can `concat`:

```js
var Payload={BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141:{questions0:"QID4",questions1:"QID17"},BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV:{questions0:"QID39",questions1:"QID38"},BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz:{questions0:"QID9",questions1:"QID7",questions2:"QID12",questions3:"QID11"},BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5:{questions0:"QID14"},BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp:{questions0:"QID30",questions1:"QID31"},BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1:{questions0:"QID5",questions1:"QID18"},BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV:{questions0:"QID13"},BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf:{questions0:"QID44"},BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B:{questions0:"QID36"},BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz:{questions0:"QID27",questions1:"QID24"},BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx:{questions0:"QID45"},BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr:{questions0:"QID29",questions1:"QID32"},BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt:{questions0:"QID43",questions1:"QID42",questions2:"QID41",questions3:"QID40",questions4:"QID34"},BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP:{questions0:"QID16",questions1:"QID15"},BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9:{questions0:"QID46"},BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr:{questions0:"QID33"}};
var keyArr=["BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf","BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt","BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B","BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141","BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR","BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx","BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9","BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV","BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1","BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz","BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz","BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr","BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp","BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV","BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP","BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr","BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5"]

var output = keyArr.reduce(function(a, key) {
  if (Payload[key]) {
    return a.concat(Object.values(Payload[key]));
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What is this "..."? It is not running when I put it into my code; I think its  too new of syntax. Can you do it using plain javascript?

Comment: That's spread syntax, and it is indeed plain Javascript - it's been part of the spec for quite a while, and can often make code more concise and easier to read. Best to upgrade your browser and use Babel and polyfills to automatically transpile code to ES5 later, but `concat` works fine too in this case

Comment: Yeah, its actually Qualtrics (www.qualtrics.com) software, where you can put javascript in a survey. I could probably pull Babel or something though. great answer either way.